# How to use SCNNodeRendererDelegate?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm new to Swift and SceneKit and trying to understand how to use SCNNodeRendererDelegate.

I have declared delegate as follows

```
class MyRender: NSObject, SCNNodeRendererDelegate {

  func renderNode(node: SCNNode, renderer: SCNRenderer, arguments: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    node.rendererDelegate!.renderNode!(node, renderer: renderer, arguments: arguments)
  }
}
```

and trying to use it

```
class GameViewController: NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var gameView: GameView!

  override func awakeFromNib(){
    // ... some code ....
    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    boxNode.geometry = SCNBox(width: 5, height: 5, length: 5, chamferRadius: 0.1)
    boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.blueColor()
    boxNode.rendererDelegate = MyRender()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
    // ... some code ....
```

After start it fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)
Please help me to understand, what am i doing wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to use a node renderer delegate *for*? As noted in answers so far, the code you have so far is nonsensical.

Comment: @rickster In this example me trying to make "empty" renderer delegate, and it fails for reasons mentioned by mnuages. I want to use it for custom node rendering, wireframe for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see three issues:

1. delegates are not retained so you have to keep the `MyRender` instance alive by assigning it to a strong variable somewhere (and instance variable for instance)
2. `rendererDelegate` is declared as `assign` and not `weak` so it's not automatically set to `nil` when the delegate is deallocated (that is a weak spot in SceneKit) so you have to set it to `nil` explicitly. Here when the `MyRender` instance is deallocated SceneKit still thinks that `boxNode` has a delegate and messages a deallocated object (the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash)
3. it seems that you will end up in an infinite loop. Your delegate methods is calling itself.

Answer (score -1):

Will Give it a shot, first you must define your class

```
 @interface YourClass : SCNView <SCNPhysicsContactDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate>
 {

 }
 @end
```

After you have done that, your class is ready to take part in the rendering and physical contacts, but you still must tell your main SCNView and SCNScene that YOURClass will take over.
you do that with :

```
 [Myview setDelegate:self];
 [[Myscene physicsWorld] setContactDelegate:self];
```

You can do that while initializing your class, i personally crate Myscene and MYview as a singleton.

After you have done that all you have to do add in your implementation file the next lines:

## pragma mark PhysicsDelegate

```
-(void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world didBeginContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{}

-(void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world didEndContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{}

-(void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world didUpdateContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{}
```

## pragma mark RenderDelegate

```
-(void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{}
-(void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer didApplyAnimationsAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{}
-(void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer didRenderScene:(SCNScene *)scene atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{}
-(void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{}
-(void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer willRenderScene:(SCNScene *)scene atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{}
```

Now you can participate in the rendering and physics delegate.

The Pragma marks are not necessary of course.
Hope this helps